# How to set configurations for my neovim in my lazyvim folder?

Tags: lua, neovim

I want to basically hide my tabs on the top of my terminal. I know I can do it using `:set showtabline = 0` but I have to keep doing this everytime I start up neovim. I thought that I could set it up in the `options.lua` file as such:

```lua
vim.opt.showtabline = 0
```

But it doesn't work. I even tried using `.vimrc` (which doesn't work as well) and I also symlink it to `.nvimrc` which also doesn't work. How can I apply this permanently or at least on neovim startup? Note that I'm using LazyVim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Lazyvim buffers/tabs are displayed via [bufferline.nvim](https://github.com/akinsho/bufferline.nvim) plugin, see https://www.lazyvim.org/plugins/ui

If you don't want to use it, you can disable it in `lua/plugins/disabled.lua` file (see https://www.lazyvim.org/configuration/plugins). Specifically, you should add:

```lua
return {
  {
    "akinsho/bufferline.nvim",
    enabled = false,
  },
}
```